# Design standard for "About" and "Options"

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml, design, ubuntu-sdk

I have seen that in many Ubuntu Touch projects that the way to do "options" (or "settings") and "about" is done with a Tab. Is that good for the design guideline of Ubuntu Touch? Is there a standard? I really think every projects should follow a line (like GNOME does) so the users don't get lost between some app with a toolBar action for settings and others with a Tab and others called "options"...

Also what about the guideline for the "About" information, should we put it into a Tab? And how? Is there a standard like there is for GNOME?

Also where should be a "new game" button of a game app, in a toolbar or in the Tab?

This things should be nice to fix so that app can be easy to understand for all users.

Standards are better than an app mess...

Comment: If there is no way to do it I can make a bug report. But where? for what paquage?

Comment: I'd try filing it in either https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ux

Comment: Thanks, I have done it already [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1199579) (ubuntu-ui-toolokit)